# URL rewriting from root to parent directory

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need to write a rule to redirect a page to a parent directory in a .htacces file.

For instance, this is my files system :

```
- a-directory
- another-directory
-- a-file
```

i've got a virtualhost which is a pointer to "a-directory"

so when i go to http//my-virtualhost/a-file, i need to go back to the parent directory and open "a-file" in the directory "another-directory".

First at all, is that possible ?
Then, how can i write this ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity, is there a reason you wouldn't just point your virtual host to "another-directory" to begin with, if everything is just redirecting there?

Assuming you can put a `.htaccess` file above "a-directory", it would just be a matter of doing something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^a-directory/(.*) another-directory/$1
```

If for whatever reason the `.htaccess` file couldn't go there, you'd need something more geared for this kind of task, like [`mod_alias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html).